# How do I merge Master into all branches of Master at once?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Here is what I am looking to do:
I have a bunch of websites that all use the same base code. I have that base code in a repository on Git. I want to create a branch of that repository for each website. Then I will add files to the branches that relate to each website it represents. When I want to make global changes to the base code of my websites I want to make the change to Master and then have all of the branches pull in those changes.

How can I set something up where I can pull changes from master to all branches at once with one line of code instead of having to go to each branch and pull in changes? Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: That's a very unusual way to share code between projects.  Typically one would create a library that was built once and then referenced by each of the individual web sites.  Is there any particular reason you are not doing it this way?

Comment: So I have it set up this way right now because all of these websites are Wordpress themes. So I have customized wordpress' backend admin area heavily and I use that for all of my websites. Every once in a while I need to make an edit to the customized backend and I want those changes to be applied to all of the websites running that theme without overriding any of the other styling done to each individual websites front end. I already do all it through git but it would be much easier to not have to go to each branch individually and just pull changes to all at once